# SQL Server: How to use CASE with LIKE on nested CASE

Tags: sql-server

I am pretty adjusting to SQL and hope someone here can help me with this.

I have a stored procedure where I would like to pass a different value depending on whether the STACK column contains a certain item name or not.
If it contains that item, then the QTYofItems would be divided by 4 and round that answer to the nearest whole number. If it doesn't contain, then just display the QTYofItems. [Please see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWlTq.jpg)

So far I only used CASE when checking for the match with a specific value so I am not sure about this one. Can someone tell me if the following is valid and correct or let me know how to write this properly (just regarding the part in brackets) ?

```
SELECT        ISNULL(dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext, dbo.WorkOrderDetails.Description) AS Description, ISNULL(dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered, '') AS QtyofItems, CASE WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext  like '552%'  AND dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE '%leg%' AND dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE '%Sled% WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext  like '550%' and   WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext  like 'Akami%'  WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext  like 'Circus%'  WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext  like 'Coast%'  WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext  like 'Chill Bar Stool%' THEN dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered/4 ELSE dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your WHEN needs to have a THEN counterpart.

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext, dbo.WorkOrderDetails.Description) AS Description, 
    ISNULL(dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered, '') AS QtyofItems, 
    CASE WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext  LIKE '552%'  
            AND dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE '%leg%' 
            AND dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE '%Sled%'
            THEN dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered/4  --<----------- Made assumptions here
        WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE '550%' 
            AND dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE 'Akami%'
            AND dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE 'Circus%'
            THEN dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered/4  --<----------- Made assumptions here
        WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE 'Coast%'
            THEN dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered/4  --<----------- Made assumptions here
        WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE 'Chill Bar Stool%'
            THEN dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered/4 
        ELSE dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered 
    END
```

Anther option you can explore...

```
SELECT
    ...
    CASE WHEN LEFT(dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext,3) IN ('552','550')
            THEN <SomeValue>
            ...
        ELSE dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered 
    END
```

Comment: After doing the CASE statements, Do you have an idea how to round the results to the nearest whole number?

Comment: you can use `ROUND(50.56,0)` and the result will be `51.00`

Answer (score 0):

First, I would start using Table Alias to make reading your sql statements easier..

something like `dbo.ItemSpecs as spec` (spec will be the alias and use that instead of the whole table name

the case statement (assuming the logic of what you want is correct) should be like this:

```
     CASE 
     WHEN (dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext  like '552%'  AND dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE '%leg%' AND dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE '%Sled%') THEN dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered/4
     WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext  like '550%' THEN dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered/4
     WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext  like 'Akami%'   THEN dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered/4
     WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext  like 'Circus%'   THEN dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered/4
     WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext  like 'Coast%'   THEN dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered/4
     WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext  like 'Chill Bar Stool%'  THEN dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered/4
      ELSE dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered 
END as stackable
```

Comment: Thanks! After doing the CASE statements, Do you have an idea how to round the results to the nearest whole number?

Comment: you can do this THEN cast(dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered/4 as decimal(13,0)) -- if you do NOT want any decimal  or you can do THEN round( dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered/4 ,0) -- if you want to see decimal places

Answer (score 0):

What I did is manual coding like:

```
CASE WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE 'Project Cantilever%' THEN dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered / 4 WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext
                      LIKE 'Revolution%' THEN dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered / 4 WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE 'Timber Cafe%' THEN dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered / 4 WHEN dbo.ItemSpecs.ConfigProptext LIKE 'Web%' THEN dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered
                      / 4 ELSE dbo.WorkOrderDetails.QtyOrdered / 4 END AS [Qty of Units]
```